# How to add the same UIButton to navigationbars all the viewcontrollers in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I had an application in which if a condition satisfies then i need a button on the navigation bars on all the view controllers ,with the same action ,I had gone through some of the possible solutions

> as creating a delegate class and

adding it in each view controller ,

> and there is always a solution like adding it in each view controller

but not sounded feasible for me ,can anybody help me on the way to achieve this ?

Comment: You could create a BaseViewController object where you add your button to navigation item and handle click events and then use it as a superview for all your view controllers

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass your Navigation controller, and in that class you can add that button on Navigation bar, if your condition satisfies.

Comment: Exactly. And then replace all the navigation controllers that you're using with the new navigation controller subclass.